# Find the area of the region bounded by the parabola $y = 2x^2$, the tangent line to this parabola at $(5, 50)$, and the $x$-axis.

Tags: calculus

[here is my step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0QYV.jpg)

This is my homework problem and my answer is $\frac{250}{3}$. But it is always wrong. What should the right answer be?

Comment: Please detail how you came up with your answer so that we can point out your mistakes and better fit your needs.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: At first i would compute the equation of the tangent line at $$P(5;50)$$

Comment: I've already renew my question with my step. Could you help me figure the problem out?